# Daemon process alongside django

Tags: python, django, architecture, celery, ipc

Like to see what others think the best architecture for the following.

I am trying to build a project that with a web front end that has the requirement to issue commands to other long running processes that will return results to the django db. The app must be scalable (in both db and processing power) and be able to run quickly.

I've thought of the following scenario but wanted to check if there is a better way.

Django web app receives instructions from a user (via web form or API) puts this 'request' into a queue (which technology would be best?) that another process (running asynchronously to gain performance, no startup costs) can consume (how does it do this? By monitoring a queue? IPC?). This app then returns the result of it's processing which needs to be put back into the django db (best to do this by another queue or direct access?)

Thoughts on sanity...and technology. Links to tutorials would be great!

- How to run the asynchronous process. Celery, host daemon process?
- How to get data to and from the main django app/db. Queues, socket IPC?
- Use of django signals in here somewhere?!

Answer (score 1):

I think you've already answered your question. Take a look at celery in more depth:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html

Using celery you can create a task queue(via RabbitMq which is the recommended queue to use). Then you can code up worker.py scripts which will contain your long running tasks. Your django web app can call the tasks defined in your workers such as:
    myfunc.delay(4)
Celery tasks can also be configured to return results or the tasks could return results by updating data in the db that is used by your Django app.

Celery allows you to scale by running multiple workers on any number of machines and you can easily add more message/task queues by adding more rabbitMq queues.

Comment: You can refer to this link which details how to both keep track of your running processes and how they can return results back: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-result-backends